# Deploying an Java web application without any app server!!?? (Docker doesn't solve it)

Tags: jakarta-ee, server

I haven"t found any circumstance where the Java web application is being deployed without any app server (i.e, glassfish, wildfly etc). Is it possible to deploy a Java web application without any kind of app server. However, I did a little research on this, and found docker (which gives the pack once deploy anywhere facility). But that"s not what I am looking for. I am looking for app server free web application development mechanism.

Comment: I believe the J2EE framework needs to run on a compliant app server, there is no way around this?  What is your requirement?

Comment: It depends what do you want to use. You can add main method `public static void main(String[] args) {
  ...
 }` But from your question is not really clear what you want to achieve...

Comment: I want to develop, and deploy a JSF application without any need of application server; consider i will use the build tool i.e. maven/etc. to build the .war file.

Comment: You can develop and deploy your application without an application server. Furthermore you also can test your application. Take a look at [Arquilian](http://arquillian.org/) or this [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfoJAshalx4) using Arquillian and Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a war file doing some JSF, you can package a JSF implementation in your WAR file, bootstrap the JSF implementation (depends on the impl you choose, but you'll probably have to decalre a servlet in the `web.xml`) and deploy it on a servlet container ([undertow](http://undertow.io/), [jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/),...).

If you don't want a servlet container either, you can try [Wildfly Swarm](http://wildfly-swarm.io/). It will basically create a auto-executable "uber-jar" file containing your application, a servlet container and a JSF implementation (and potentially other Java EE components you may need like CDI, JPA, etc). They provide a maven plugin to easily create such jar file.

Then, you just have to run this uber-jar file (`java -jar your-jar-file.jar`), and your application will run, without having installed any app server nor servlet container. But it is not suitable for development, since you'll need to recreate the uber-jar very often.

If you are just looking for a "web application development mechanism" for JSF, the best approach to me is still an app server with an IDE like Eclipse or Intellij. The IDE will be able to publish your changes on the app server without restarting the app server. Which is very convenient for development.